# Changing the style of the references?

Tags: bibliographies

I'm pretty new to LaTeX but it is an amazing tool so I try to solve my problems one by one.

I have to write a report, and the style of the references have to be in a "Animal Behaviour" style. 
For example:

> **Hanski, I**. 1998. Metapopulation dynamics. *Nature*, **396**, 41–49.

The problem is that, with BibTeX (I use Mendeley Desktop too) and the `\bibliographystyle{apalike}`, it gives me this:

> Hanski, I. (1998). Metapopulation dynamics. *Nature*, 396:41–49.

I searched a way to make my own reference style and saw things like `biblatex` but I don't get all of the explained informations...
Is there an easy way to change just 1 or 2 parameters of my references style?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Comment: It looks like you need to make at least three changes to the `apalike` bibliography style in order to achieve your desired style; moreover, `apalike` doesn't feature a function to typeset material in boldface, and you'll thus have to provide one in order to achieve some of your desired effects. I would thus recommend that you *not* try to "hack" the file `apalike.bst`. Instead, I would suggest you use the `makebst` utility -- at the command line, type `latex makebst` to get started, then follow the detailed prompts -- to create a custom bibliography style that's fully tailored to your needs.

Comment: @ Peter. Well received! Did not visit a forum since a long time so the rules change ... @Mico Thanks, ti swas exactly the tool I was trying to search. I'll try to tame it!